# How to add left and top parameters to javascript open in new window code

Tags: javascript

How can I rewrite the following so I can also state the 'left' and 'top' parameters so I can centre the popup?

```
    $('.open-new-window').click(function(){
      var window_width = $(this).data("window-width"),
        window_height = $(this).data("window-height"),
        window_name = $(this).data("name");
      window.open(this.href, window_name, 'width=' + window_width + ', height=' + window_height); 
      return false;
    });
```

Ive tried many variations of this:

```
    $('.open-new-window').click(function(){
      var window_width = $(this).data("window-width"),
        window_height = $(this).data("window-height"),
        window_name = $(this).data("name");
      window.open(this.href, window_name, left='100px', top='100px, 'width=' + window_width + ', height=' + window_height); 
      return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (settings inside the string):

```
var settings = 'width=300, height=500, top=20, left=20, scrollbars=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no, resizable=yes, dependent=no';
var win = window.open(popupUrl, popupTitle, settings);
```

Here is complete example:

```
<a class="open-new-window" data-window-width="300" data-window-height="350" data-window-url="path_to_file.html" data-window-top="30" data-window-left="30" data-window-title="My Window" href="path_to_file.html">Open Popup</a>

$('.open-new-window').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisLink = $(this);
    var windowUrl = thisLink.data("windowUrl");
    var windowWidth = thisLink.data("windowWidth"),
    var windowHeight = thisLink.data("windowHeight"),
    var windowTitle = thisLink.data("windowTitle");
    var windowTop = thisLink.data("windowTitle");
    var windowLeft = thisLink.data("windowTitle");
    var settings = 'width=' + windowWidth + ', height=' + windowHeight + ', top=' + windowTop + ', left=' + windowLeft + ', scrollbars=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no, resizable=yes, dependent=no';
    window.open(windowUrl, windowTitle, settings); 
});
```

Comment: I need width and height to be calculated (like it is in my code).

Comment: skobaljic's point was about using a string of options as a set of settings passed to the `window.open` rather than giving them one by one separated by commas. So you can always inject the dimensions into the string by concatenating them into it.

Comment: Updated answer. As I can see you had problems with elements `data` attributes, you can read about them [in this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/)